# Map giving same data of object while using loop

Tags: apex, batch

I am using a batch class where data iterated over an object

---

Now i am trying to retrieve some fields iterating over object1

Issue - its giving me common id for provider Base value

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your post. You can use the `{}` button or wrap in triple backticks (```) to format code blocks.

Comment: Right now, it's not clear what your issue is. Please [edit] your question to be more descriptive.

Comment: Removing the code from your question does not make it more descriptive. See [ask] for how to phrase questions.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your formatting of code may have confused you. As written, you have a for loop within a for loop, so the values are getting written over and over again.

At minimum, this should help:

```
for(Object1__c obj : scope) {
    lt.add(obj.Id);
    system.debug('obj Id' +obj.Id);
}
for(object2 mmisPanel : [Some Soql query FROM Object1__c WHERE LTMS_Tracking_Number__c IN : track1 ] ){
    Map1.put(mmp.RecordType.Name, mmte);
    Map2.put(mmp.lt__r.PID_SL__r.PI_c,Map1);
}
```

Comment: Hi,
i am not using nested loop it was a null check condition which i forgot to edit while pasting the code here.

Issue : ltmsTrackingList is having more than one data. 
Soql query also having more than one data. When i iterate over the loop to get the value .. it showing common value and not other values which should be stored in the Map

Comment: am i missing something here while storing values for Map1/Map2??

Comment: @VISHALBADONI When you put a new value in a map, the old value gets removed. Since you're using RecordType.Name, you probably want to make the value of the map a list so you can get all the values.